# How do I get all attributes of a Model minus a few

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

So I'm writing a rspec test. It will test if a model is duplicated correctly. So the spec is something like this:

> ```
>   it "should copy the data" do
>     @model = build(:model)
>     @another_model.copy_data(@model)
>     @model.data.should == @another_model.data
>   end
> ```

The data is a embedded document so it is duplicated when I do this. All the attributes on the model is copied over successfully minus the id and the created_at date. Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
    @model.data.attributes.without(:_id, :created_at).should == @another_model.data.attributes.without(:_id, :created_at)
```

Or the other way around where I select all the other fields without the id and created_at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This works

```
@model.attributes.except("id", "created_at").should == @another_model.attributes.except("id", "created_at")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this since `.attributes` returns a Hash where the each key-value pair is an attribute along with its value.

```
@model.data.attributes.each do |k,v|
  next if k == 'id' || k == 'created_at' # Skip if the key is id or created_at
  v.should == @another_model.data.attributes[k]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

model.attribute_names.reject { |att| att if %w(id created_at updated_at).include? att }

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but nobody has suggested:

```rb
@model.attributes - %w(id, created_at)
```

Seems clean.